# date_field - can't convert Symbol into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm quite fresh ruby on rails developer and i'm experiencing some troubles with displaying `date_field` in user profile edit form. It suddenly stopped working and i can't debug what's wrong and why it's not working. Here is my code:

**_form.html.haml**

```
= form_for(@profile) do |f|
  = f.label :dob, 'Date of birth', :class => 'control-label'
  = f.date_select :dob, :start_year => Time.now.year - 50, :end_year => Time.now.year - 5, :include_blank => true
```

It gives me the following error:

> can't convert Symbol into String

on line 26 which is the one with `date_select`. I'm getting this error no matter if `dob` field is empty or not. Have you any idea what am i possibly missing? The strange thing is that it was working yesterday.

Comment: The obvious question is what have you changed between yesterday and today?

Comment: oh yes, i'm asking myself the same question but there was so much modifications that i can't even remember all of them

Comment: Are you using version control?

Comment: unfortunately not, but all of the changes i've made were done mainly in views so i don't think that's the reason

Comment: haha believe me, i'm way more sad than you are but don't worry, i'll figure it out, it need's to be something really simple

Comment: For anothers which have this error:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423660/cant-convert-symbol-into-string ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423660/cant-convert-symbol-into-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe a little late, but I found something here:

http://i18n.lighthouseapp.com/projects/14947/tickets/12-i18n-and-date_select-exception

Best regards,
Dinah

edit: I had to change date order in locale .yml to

```
 -    order: [ :year, :month, :day ]
 +    order:
 +      - :year
 +      - :month
 +      - :day
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a translation problem: you have to add `:order` rule to your `it.yml` file or add `:order` as a param in your form.

```
= f.date_select :dob, :start_year => Time.now.year - 50, 
                      :end_year => Time.now.year - 5, 
                      :order => [:day, :month, :year],
                      :include_blank => true
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem working with i18n. Everything worked perfectly fine for English; but the view threw a "**can't convert Symbol into String**" error when viewing with another language.

The Solution I used was to set the language for the "date_select" adding ":locale" like this:

```
<%= f.date_select(:admissionyear, :start_year => 1940, :end_year => Date.today.year, :discard_day => true, :discard_month => true, :locale => 'en') %>
```

That way you wont need to add things to other i18n yml files when using other languages.

Answer (score 0):

The signature for the [data_select function](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html) has two string params to start it, the hash doesn't begin until the third param:

date_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})

So, you need:

**date_select(:user, :dob,  :start_year => Time.now.year - 50, :end_year => Time.now.year - 5, :include_blank => true)**

Comment: This is the form builder version which doesn't require the first parameter because it's implied. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-date_select

Comment: above code is wrapped in `form_for` block, that's why there were no object parameter but even if i'll use your code with `@object`, it still gives me the same error.