# can't convert Symbol into String

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code in Ruby, take directly from the [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide

```
 def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  @post.save
  redirect_to @post
end

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end
```

When I run the above `Create` I get the following error.

> can't convert Symbol into string

Comment: and what's the question????

Comment: What is the error full backtrace? Provide more data.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to use **strong paramaters**. You get this error **cannot convert symbol into string** because you have not configured the strong_parameters. So by default you cant use require on params with symbols.

Configure strong parameters as follows:

```
1.) Add gem 'strong_parameters' to your gemfile and bundle it.
2.) Include Restrictions to you model as follows.
       include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection to your model.
3.) Disable white listing in application confiuration(config/application.rb)
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) for more details on configuring.

Now your code should work.

Comment: this should be enough 1.) Add gem 'strong_parameters' to your gemfile and bundle it.

Comment: @d1jhoni1b is correct. I tested it, just had to restart the server to get it to work after bundling.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is using Mongoid, you can fix this issue by adding the following to an initializer:

```
Mongoid::Document.send(:include, ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add gem 'strong_parameters' to the gem file and 
run >bundle install in command prompt
Refresh the browser.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Could you please expand on your answer?