# can't convert symbol into string ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am stuck in very weird problem. I have 2 models `User` and `Supplier`. User can add many suppliers so here is how my model looks like.
here is my User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
.
.
.
     has_many :suppliers, dependent: :destroy

     def Supplier_feed
         Supplier.where("user_id = ?", id)
     end
end
```

My supplier model is like

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_primary_key :id 

  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
  validates :supplier, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

My controller looks like

```
class SuppliersController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    @user=current_user
    @supplier = current_user.suppliers.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @supplier=Supplier.new
  end


  def create
    @supplier = current_user.suppliers.build(supplier_params)
    if @supplier.save
      flash[:success] = "Supplier created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @supplier_feed_items = []
      render 'users/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

      def supplier_params
      params.require(:suppliers).permit(:supplier)
    end
end
```

When i try to add some supplier i get the error

```
 TypeError in SuppliersController#create

can't convert Symbol into String
```

Here is how my form looks like.

```
<%= form_for :suppliers, :url => {:action => "create"} do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :supplier, placeholder: "Add new Supplier..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

As i am new to RoR i am, unable to figure out what wrong i have done.
Please guide me to proper direction. Thanks in advance

**Edit**
My application Trace is like

```
app/controllers/suppliers_controller.rb:32:in `supplier_params'
app/controllers/suppliers_controller.rb:16:in `create'

This error occurred while loading the following files:
   supplier
```

My request parameters are

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"1op5Kkh6EXO+wsR9TmAY1SW3ZIUNYcrodbJ9lfpJjck=",
 "suppliers"=>{"supplier"=>"abc"},
 "commit"=>"Post"}
```

Here is my Add supplier form.

```
<%= form_for :suppliers, :url => {:action => "create"} do |f| %> 
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :supplier, placeholder: "Add new Supplier..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I am using partial. so here is my view suppliers

```
<div class="span8">
    <% if @user.suppliers.any? %>
      <h3>Suppliers (<%= @user.suppliers.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="supplierss">
        <%= render @supplier %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @supplier %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

here is my `_Suppliers.html.erb`

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= supplier.supplier %></span>
  </span>
</li>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423660/cant-convert-symbol-into-string

Comment: i tried that sir. but this gem didn't fixed my prob. i have done all my research then came to ask question :)

Comment: "has_many :suppliers, dependent: :destroy.", is the trailing dot in your actual code ?

Comment: Then try to submit the form without strong parameters as show in answer

Comment: also, when you show an error, please provide a stack trace so we can see quickly where error occurs without having to guess

Comment: @OlivierElMekki it is a typo. not in my original code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typo error in view

You have used

```
def new
   @supplier=Supplier.new
end
```

And in view you have used

```
<%= form_for :suppliers, :url => {:action => "create"} do |f| %>
```

in the view `:suppliers` must be `supplier` delete `s` from `suppliers`

Please use

```
def new
  @supplier=Supplier.new
end

<%= form_for :supplier, :url => {:action => "create"} do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :supplier, placeholder: "Add new Supplier..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: the error is gone. but i cant see any value added.i guess now the problem is with my parameters. well thanks for the pointing out my idiotic mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You create a form like this

```
<%= form_for @supplier do |f| %>
```

and in controller

def create

```
@supplier = current_user.suppliers.build(params[:supplier])
```

Comment: now i am getting error `undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class' here is the source of error `1: <%= form_for @supplier do |f| %>
2:   
3:   <div class="field">
4:     <%= f.text_area :supplier, placeholder: "Add new Supplier..." %>' line `
it says issue is aroung line 1.

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri Can you paste your code after adding `<%= form_for @supplier do |f| %> `

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri I want to say please paste your view code i.e. `<%= form_for @suppliers %>`

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri please use `<%= form_for @suppliers do |f| %> ` and it will work

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri I have updated my answer please take a look there